# Possible to retrieve a Salesforce campaign name based on campaign id for use in Marketing Cloud landingpage?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, campaign

I have a landing page in Marketing Cloud which I populate dynamically depending on variables in the url.

The landing page is accessed from a link in an email. Purpose is to get people to sign up and join a SF campaign.

The id of the campaign sits in a parameter in the url.

I would like to retrieve the Campaign name from Salesforce.
Do you know how to do that in ampscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Salesforce API calls to burn, you would create a landing page in Cloud Pages from code and use the AMPScript [QueryParameter function](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/queryparameter/#QueryParameter) to retrieve the ID of the Campaign from the URL to the landing page:

```
SET @SFCampaignID = QueryParameter("cid")
```

You'd then use the AMPScript function [RetrieveSalesforceObjects](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/retrievesalesforceobjects/) to get the name of the Campaign:

```
/* RetrieveSalesforceObjects returns a rowset */
SET @Campaigns = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Campaign", "Name", "Id", "=", @SFCampaignID)

/# Take the name field from the first row of @Campaigns */
SET @CampaignName = Field(Row(@Campaigns,1),"Name")
```

Finally, you'd spit out the name of the campaign on your page:

```
Thanks for signing up for %%=v(@CampaignName)=%%
```

Pragmatically, I'd opt for importing the Campaigns object into SFMC either use [imports](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/) or [Data Stream](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/features/synchronized_data_sources/) and using [LookupRows](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookuprows/#LookupRows) to get the data that's been staged in SFMC Data Extensions. You'd end up with a slightly faster page load and not needlessly waste CRM API calls/quota.